# Error en código al traer datos de un formulario con node js

Tags: html, nodejs

Estoy tratando de traer datos de un input con node js, la pagina carga bien el error es cuando envio una cadena me lanza un error.
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {


    fs.readFile("./form.html", function(err, html) {

        var html_string = html.toString();
        var arreglo_parametros = [],parametros = {};

        var variables =html_string.match((/[^\{\}]+(?=\})/g));
        var nombre = "";
        if (req.url.indexOf("?") > 0) {

            var url_data= req.url.split();
            var arreglo_parametros = url_data[1].split("&");//error
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arreglo_parametros.length; i++) {
            var parametro = arreglo_parametros[i];

            var param_data = parametros.split("=");

            parametros[param_data[0]] = [param_data[1]];


        }


        for(var i=variables.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
            //Lo ejecutamos como codigo javaScript
            //para obtener el valor de dicha variable
            var value = eval(variables[i]);

            html_string = html_string.replace("{" + variables[i] + "}",parametros[variables]);


        };

        resp.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"})

        resp.write(html_string);

        resp.end();

    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Y al enviar el dato me tira este errror:

> var arreglo_parametros = url_data[1].split("&");//buscar error
>   /home/mrdestroyer/curso_node/enviar_formulario/parametros_formularios.js:23:49
>   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:447:3)

Comment: Ummm ... Creo que acabara cerrada como `error tipográfico` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error es muy sencillo; de la documentacion de la MSN:

#### String.prototype.split( [separador] [,limite] )

**separador**

> Especifica el carácter a usar para la separación de la cadena. El separador es tratado como una cadena o como una expresión regular. Si se omite el separador, el arreglo devuelto contendrá un sólo elemento con la cadena completa.

Por lo tanto, cuando tu haces

```
var url_data= req.url.split();
```

Lo que obtienes es un `Array` de **1 solo elemento**, cuyo índice es **`0`**.

Por lo tanto, aquí

```
var arreglo_parametros = url_data[1].split("&");//error
```

Estas accediendo al índice equivocado: el único índice válido de `url_data` es el `0`, mientras que tú estás intentando acceder al índice `1`.

Si lo que quieres es acceder a los *argumentos* pasados en la solicitud, lo correcto es:

```
var url_data= req.url.split( '?' );
```